# How to open application settings programmatically in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms, I would like to know how to open the settings page of my application programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin.Essentials package supports this functionality:

`Xamarin.Essentials.AppInfo.ShowSettingsUI`

See [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/app-information?tabs=android#displaying-application-settings) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface ISystemSettings
{
    void OpenApplicationDetailsSettings();
}
```

iOS

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SystemSettings))]
public class SystemSettings : ISystemSettings
{
    public void OpenApplicationDetailsSettings()
    {
        var ApplicationUrl = new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(ApplicationUrl);
    }
}
```

Android

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SystemSettings))]
public class SystemSettings : ISystemSettings
{
    public void OpenApplicationDetailsSettings()
    {
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(
            Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
            Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName)));
    }
}
```